# Not able to get a post to display to my main page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am creating a blog. I am trying to get the output of my post to show in my "news feed". I dont get any error when executing, but the post wont display on the page.

**post.js**

```
router.get("/", (req,res,next) => {
        
})

router.post("/", async(req,res,next) => {

    if(req.body.content){
        console.log("Content param not sent with request");
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }

    var postData = {
        content: req.body.content,
        postedBy: req.session.user
    }

    Post.create(postData)
    .then(async newPost => {
        newPost = await User.populate(newPost, { path: "postedBy"})
    
        res.status(201).send(newPost);
    
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(400);
    })
})


module.exports = router;
```

**common.js**

```
$("#submitPostButton").click(() => {
    var button = $(event.target);
    var textbox = $("#postTextarea");

    var data = {
        conent: textbox.val()
    }

    $.post("/api/posts",data,postData => {
        var html = createPostHtml(postData);
        $(".postsContainer").prepend(html);
        textbox.val("");
        button.prop("disabled", true);
    })
})

function createPostHtml(postData){
    return postData.conent;
}
```

my **PUG** code:

```
extends layouts/main-layout.pug

block content 
    +createPostForm(userLoggedIn)
    .postsContainer
```

Again, i am not getting any errors in the console. the data is just not showing on the page.

Comment: try console logging postData both at backend and frontend

Comment: is `return postData.conent;` just a typo here or is this also in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use async/await paradagm, try to replace

```
try {
    const newPost = await Post.create(postData)
    const newPostWithUser = await User.populate(newPost, { path: "postedBy"})
    res.status(201).send(newPost);
}
catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(400);
}
```

after this check your front code and look does data get back from backend or not